# show a view part from another using a button

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I want to open a ViewPart from a button in the ViewPart of another button.. I am using eclipse RCP and rcp viewparts.

My code:

```
Button btnPush = new Button(container, SWT.NONE);
btnPush.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        // i want to display the view from here

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the workbench page. In a view part you can use

```
IWorkbenchPage page = getSite().getPage();
```

elsewhere use:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
```

Show and activate the view:

```
page.showView("view id");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but using those functions the view appears next to the old view i want it to pop up

Comment: That is not at all straightforward.

Comment: That will involve coding Placeholders into the perspective or using PerspectiveExtensions
http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/eclipseplugins/032142672X/ch10lev1sec2.html